# How to see if a service is running on Linux?

Tags: linux, systemctl

I'm using systemctl to setup and run my serviced on a Linux Redhat. How can I check if a service is in running state?

I can use

```
systemctl is-active <service name>
```

to check if the service is is active or not. But I would like to check if the service is in the substate running.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`systemctl status name.service`

check this out

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-services

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo service httpd status

OR you can check with list of services

$netstat -plnt